# Tomcat 7 vs. ehCache Standalone Server (Glassfish) Configuration with RESTful Web Services

Tags: tomcat, soap, glassfish, tomcat7, ehcache

My requirements consist of using ehCache to send and store data via RESTful web service calls. The data can be stored in-memory or via the filesystem...

Never used ehCache before so I am having some issues deciding on which bundle to use.

Have downloaded the following bundles:

- ehcache-2.6.2
- ehcache-standalone-server-1.0.0

(1) What is the difference between the two?

It seems the ehcache-2.6.2 contains src and binaries, which essentially enables one to bundle it with their webapps (by putting the compiled jar or binaries inside the webapp's WEB-INF/lib folder). But it doesn't seem that it has support for Restful web services.

Whereas, ehcache-standalone-server-1.0.0 (comes with an embedded Glassfish server and has support for REST & SOAP) can be used to run as a standalone server. If I my answers to my own question are correct, then that means, I should just use the standalone server?

(2) My requirements are to setup ehCache (with REST support) on Tomcat 7. So, how could I setup ehCache on Tomcat 7 as a separate app with REST & SOAP support?

Thank you for taking the time to read this...

Comment: Did you try "RESTful cache server in a WAR" download http://ehcache.org/downloads/destination?name=ehcache-server-1.0.0-distribution.tar.gz&bucket=tcdistributions&file=ehcache-server-1.0.0-distribution.tar.gz  This download lacks sl4j impl libraries.

Comment: I don't see the "RESTful cache server in a WAR" download that you mention in that link. That link is for the ehCache Standalone Server (which has an embedded Glassfish instance).

Comment: Prashanth, yes, I do see the download you are talking about, it was located actually in sourceforge (the one on the ehcache website is broken). Thanks for the tip regarding sl4j impl libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prashanth should get some credit for this but he didn't post the solution as an answer but as a comment.

To setup tomcat there's some additional things that need to be done:

- Download ehcache-server-1.0.0 from (not from ehcache.org/downloads - that file is broken):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ehcache/files/ehcache-server/

- Untar the zip file and rename it to ehcache.war
- Unzip the ehcache.war file and download the slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar (this contains the impl) and place it inside:

ehcache/WEB-INF/lib/

- Move the ehcache dir under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
- Run tomcat

Use one of the example REST calls to test ehcache, here's the URL for the scripts:

http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.5/modules/cache-server